# How do I test the hypothesis that one parameter increases while another does not decrease?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

### The Problem Setting

#### Prose Description

I have a feature that I might roll out on my website. I only want to do this, however, if this feature increases the average amount that a customer spends while not negatively impacting the conversion rate. This is because I believe the feature cannot positively impact conversion rate but could possibly decrease it.

#### Mathematical Description

We run an AB test, where group A receives the new version of the website and group B receives the old version of the website.

We define the parameter $s_A$ to be the average spending of a customer in group A and $s_B$ to be the average spending of a customer in group B. Likewise, we define $c_A$ to be the conversion rate of customers in group A and $c_B$ to be the conversion rate of customers in group B.

Let us also assume that we have independent estimators of all of these parameters $\hat{s}_A, \hat{s}_B, \hat{c}_A, \hat{c}_B$.

Lastly, we want to make decision 1 if $s_A > s_B$ and
$c_A \ge c_B$ and decision 0 otherwise.

### My Question

Is it sufficient to set two alpha values, one to test $s_A > s_B$ and one to test $c_A < c_B$, only accepting the AB test as successful if I reject the first hypothesis and fail to reject the second hypothesis?

Comment: I wonder about the relative merits of testing qA<qB versus looking at the correlation (linear or otherwise) between p and q.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking because you do not seem to have formulated a definite hypothesis and you appear to use technical terms, especially "parameter," in a nonstandard way.  Could you provide some more background or explanation of what you are actually doing, what these "parameters" are, and how they are measured, determined, or estimated?

Comment: okay I edited the question to make it clearer. Obviously my brain has been broken by working as a data scientist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I'm not a big fan of one-sided tests. I'll assume (hopefully I'm reading the question correctly) that you can call the A version successful if in truth $s_A > s_B$ and $c_A \leq c_B$. In that case my first instinct to would be to create Bonferonni-corrected 2-sided confidence intervals for $s_A - s_B$ and $c_A - c_B$, and be happy if they are fall above and (respectively) on or below zero. That way, even if you don't hit that joint result, you still understand the effect of the A version.

Bonferonni confidence intervals are formed by bonferonni-correcting the confidence level. So make a $(1 - \alpha/m)\times 100\%$ interval for each parameter, which by a union bound gives overall $1-\alpha$ confidence for the intervals (by the standard interpretation). See for instance [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc473.htm).